# how to get a folder icon attached to a Folder in a Listview in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

How do I attach a folder icon to a ListView folder? This is what I have tried:

[image: Icons]

```
Do While sFolderName <> ""
    For i = 0 To dirList.ListCount - 1  
    w = 1    
    hIcon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(App.hInstance, "C:\Windows", 3)
    If sFolderName <> "" And sFolderName <> "" Then
        If (GetAttr(sPath & sFolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ListView2.ListItems.add , , sFolderName, Picture2.Picture
            Picture2.AutoRedraw = True
            Picture2.Cls
            DrawIcon Me.Picture2, 0, 0, hIcon
        End If

        'Tried the below same result
        If IsNull(hIcon) Then
            picBuff.Picture = Picture2.Picture
            'picDefault.Picture
        Else
            'Set picBuff.Picture = Picture2.Picture
            'Set picBuff.Picture = Nothing
            'DoEvents
            'picBuff.Picture = Picture2.Picture      
            'DrawIcon picBuff.hdc, 0, 0, hIcon
            'DoEvents
        End If
        sFolderName = Dir
    End If
    ...
Loop
```

---

(Edit: converted into legible text, although it consists of an image and code only. Herb.)

Comment: You need to add the icon to an ImageList, associate the ImageList with ListView2, then set the Icon parameter in the Add method to the Key used when you added hte icon to the ImageList.

Comment: Hi Jac and thank you for your reply and the above posted code is a bit of a mess, and I have added a icon image to a ImageList I had and it wasnt displaying the icon, until I changed 1 thing one digit in the calling of the icon out of the Imagelist, my sincere thanks

Comment: base64, just add 4 blanks at the beginning of each code line, and your code is no mess any longer.